# How Can I read URLs from text file located on my PC?

Tags: python

I have a python code that scraps data from a website. This code works fine, but I want to change the URL source to a text list on my desktop. The urls in my text file are each one in a line.
How do you suggest I should read this file and loop through urls?
Thanks in advance for your time.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
csv_file = open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['name', 'link', 'price'])
for x in range(0, 70):
    try:
        urls = 'https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html&pagesize[]=24&order[]=new&stock[]=1&page[]=' + str(x + 1) + '&ajax=ok?_=1561559181560'
        source = requests.get(urls).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        print('Page: %s' % (x + 1))
        for figcaption in soup.find_all('figcaption'):
           price = figcaption.find('span', {'class': 'new_price'}).text.strip()
           name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
           link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']
           print('%s\n%s\n%s' % (price, name, link))
           csv_writer.writerow([name, link, price])
    except:
        break
csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many URLs in that text file (*urls.txt* in my example) the following snippet should do what you want.

```py
import requests

# read all URLs at once
with open("urls.txt", "r") as f:
    urls = f.read().splitlines()

# and loop over them
for url in urls:
    try:
        source = requests.get(url).text
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have a file called input.txt which looks like this

```
url1
url2
url3
url4
.
.
.
```

Then we will simply open this **input.txt** file and then split by a newline('\n'). This should give us a list of urls. 
like

```
['url1','url2','url3']
```

You can then simply loop through it and crawl the webpages.

Here is a

```
# crawler.py

import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('input.txt','r') as f:
  urls = f.read().split() # here we get a list of urls 

csv_file = open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['name', 'link', 'price'])
for url in urls:
    try:

        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        for figcaption in soup.find_all('figcaption'):
           price = figcaption.find('span', {'class': 'new_price'}).text.strip()
           name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
           link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']
           print('%s\n%s\n%s' % (price, name, link))
           csv_writer.writerow([name, link, price])
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      break


csv_file.close()
```